# Use background-size WITHOUT scaling the image

Tags: css

I want to use background-size for css-sprites. Is it possible to use this property without having the browser scale down the image? What i would like to achieve is hide the part of the sprite that isn't contained within the background-size.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to used background size to hide parts of a sprite. In your css classes you should specify which part of the sprite you want to use by using pixel values i.e:

CSS:

```
#groupIcon{width:70px; height:70px;}
.groupIcon1{background:url(../images/groupIconsSprite.png) 0 0;}
.groupIcon2{background:url(../images/groupIconsSprite.png) -70px 0;}
.groupIcon3{background:url(../images/groupIconsSprite.png) -140px 0;}
.groupIcon4{background:url(../images/groupIconsSprite.png) -210px 0;}
.groupIcon5{background:url(../images/groupIconsSprite.png) -280px 0;}
```

Then all you need to do is change the class of the div in question and the desired section of the sprite will be used

```
<div id="groupIcon" class="groupIcon1"></div>
```

or

```
<div id="groupIcon" class="groupIcon2"></div>
```

If this doesn't solve your problem then you will have to be a bit more specific and provide code snippets